# Docker poor speed of locahost on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

After intalling `Docker` on windows and setting some settings for that. after opening `firefox` and locating `localhost` its take a long time to opening my web application which i should see on browser. as far i installed `Ubuntu` linux from windows store i'm not sure my projects should be placed on that or not. without considering ubuntu installation i created `.wslconfig` into user directory with this content:

```
[wsl2]
memory=4GB # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 4 GB
processors=2 # Makes the WSL 2 VM use two virtual processors
```

please look at this screen shot

[image]

Comment: You should make a benchmark route. One that doesn't actually do anything and only returns a single string response. What you shared is `authentication/...` which may (or may not) do more things like access a database etc. This should help you figure out where the slowdown is

Comment: @apokryfos i tested this project on `ubuntu` it doesn't have any issue and speed of `localhost` is very fast